# Exception when using ASP.NET Core Data Protection

Tags: .net-core, azure-keyvault

It seems random, but happens quite often, but when I visit the main page of my app, I sometimes get a 500. The exception I'm getting:

```
An error occurred while trying to encrypt the provided data. Refer to the inner exception for more information.
StackTrace:
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(Byte[] plaintext) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.SecureDataFormat`1.Protect(TData data, String purpose) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.SecureDataFormat`1.Protect(TData data) at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.WriteNonceCookie(String nonce) at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties) at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties) at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties) at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result) at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAlwaysRunResultFilters() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync() at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync() at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.StatusCodePagesMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I'm pretty much following the guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2

I have created this extension method:

```
    private static IServiceCollection AddDataProtection<TConfig, TLogger>(this IServiceCollection services, TConfig config) where TLogger : StandardLogger where TConfig : FrontEndAppConfigBase
    {

        if (Environment.MachineName.StartsWith("shal", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return services;
        if (!OAuthConfiguration.UseKeyVaultDataProtection) return services;
        var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
        var tokenCredential = new TokenCredential(azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://storage.azure.com/").Result);
        var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(tokenCredential);
        var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, "foocommonprotection", "core.windows.net", true);

        services.AddDataProtection(options => { options.ApplicationDiscriminator = config.ApplicationName; })
           .SetApplicationName(config.ApplicationName)
           .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(storageAccount, $"footokenprotectionkeys/{config.ServiceName ?? config.ApplicationName}{config.AppEnvironment}/keys.xml")
           .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback)), $"{config.KeyVaultUrl}keys/dataProtectionKey");
        return services;
    }
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to change the implementation like below:

```
{
  "DataProtection": {
    "KeyVaultKeyId": "https://mykeyvaultname.vault.azure.net/keys/DataProtectionKey/bfc1bda979bc4081b89ab6f43bad12b8"
  }
}

var kvClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(_tokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

services.AddDataProtection()
    .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(kvClient, settings.KeyVaultKeyId);
```

In startup.cs:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(kvClient, settings.KeyVaultKeyId);
    // Replicates PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage
    // There is no overload to give it the func it ultimately uses
    // We need to do that so that we can get refreshed tokens when needed
services.Configure<KeyManagementOptions>(options =>
{
    options.XmlRepository = new AzureBlobXmlRepository(() =>
    {
        // This func is called every time before getting the blob and before modifying the blob
        // Get access token for Storage
        // User / managed identity needs Blob Data Contributor on the Storage Account (container was not enough)
        string accessToken = _tokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://storage.azure.com/", tenantId: settings.AadTenantId)
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
        // Create blob reference with token
        var tokenCredential = new TokenCredential(accessToken);
        var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(tokenCredential);
        var uri = new Uri($"https://{settings.StorageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/{settings.StorageKeyContainerName}/{settings.StorageKeyBlobName}");
        // Note this func is expected to return a new instance on each call
        var blob = new CloudBlockBlob(uri, storageCredentials);
        return blob;
    });
});
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://joonasw.net/view/using-azure-key-vault-and-azure-storage-for-asp-net-core-data-protection-keys).

Comment: KeyVaultClient is being deprecated in favor of SecretClient, available in our new package, Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets. We also split KeyClient and CertificateClient into separate packages. See https://aka.ms/valueprop and https://aka.ms/intro for more information. Used with DefaultAzureCredential from Azure.Identity, these are easier to use and do not require code changes from development to production environments. We also have configuration builders that are easier to use - often just requiring a Key Vault URI.

Comment: I recently blogged about how you can store the key ring in Azure Key Vault here https://www.edument.se/en/blog/post/storing-the-asp-net-core-data-protection-key-ring-in-azure-key-vault